# How do I write to a CSV with the data ending up in separate columns (currently using arcpy in python 2.7)

Tags: python, arcpy

I'm working with arcpy to pull information from a shapefile and putting that info into a CSV. What I want is 3 separate columns with the information, but currently they merge into on giant column.

The code:

```
f3 = open('ChannelWidth.CSV','a')

cursor2 = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("IntersectPy",['FID','TIME',"SHAPE@LENGTH"])
for row in cursor2:
    f3.write(str(row[0]))
    f3.write(str(row[1]))
    f3.write(str(row[2]))

del cursor2
f3.close()
```

[And here's a picture of the current output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2kgy.png)

What I want is like:

```
0   1500   0.001334166
1   1500   0.001335145
```

and so on...

So my question is what can I do to separate those values out?

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in cursor2:
    f3.write(str(row[0]) + "\t " + str(row[1]) + "\t " + str(row[2]))
```

Should solve this.

Comment: Unfortunately it makes one long row instead of 3 columns. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: swap the `,` for a tab `\t` if you want tab delimited.  I thought you were writing a csv...  `    f3.write(str(row[0]) + "\t " + str(row[1]) + "\t " + str(row[2]))`